# What elements on a Stack Exchange site can be changed by a community mod?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderator-abilities, trusted-user

I've found a problem with the close text for the off-topic reason on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), and would like to modify it.  (Note: I've opened a meta question for the change [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/754/should-the-off-topic-close-text-be-changed), but I think the change is pretty obvious.)

Can a trusted user or a community moderator do this, or does this require a developer's action?

More generally, what site elements can be changed by high-rep users or community moderators, and how do these users access these options?

Comment: What Michael said. The close text for the off-topic reason is the same close text that is used on all StackExchange sites: *Questions on [this site's name] are expected to generally relate to [this site's subject], within the scope defined in the faq.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I wasn't proposing a name change or structure change. The problem is that [this site's subject] is implemented as the word 'electronics' on EE, which is misleading and confusing for the two most common off-topic close reasons (consumer electronics and purchasing electronics).  Both are about electronics, but both are off topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Where else is [this site's subject] used on the site?

Comment: I believe it is used in the welcome banner, as in "Welcome to the Q&A for [this site's subject]"

Comment: Out of curiosity, why wasn't your site named ["Electronic Engineering?"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_engineering) Seems like a better fit. Electrical Engineering also encompasses things like three-phase power and transmission lines. Are those sorts of subjects on-topic for your site?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Let's see if this fits in a comment.  If not, [here's a history post.](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/586/what-is-chiphacker/601#601).  Basically, there was Chiphacker, then Electronics Exchange[sic], then Chiphacker became Electronics and Robotics while Electronics Exchange was deleted in a move from SE 1.0, then Electronics and Robotics became Electronics Design due to a change in scope, then Electronics Design became Electronics due to a trademark violation, then Electronics became Electrical Engineering.

Comment: Well, it didn't fit, because I ought to add [this post on the most recent site title change](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565/announcement-site-title-change/566#566), where I actually advocated Electronic**s** Engineering.  Here we go again....

Comment: If I read you correctly, questions about house wiring and power lines would be on-topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: House wiring would be a better fit for [DIY](http://diy.stackexchange.com/); *design* is a key part of our scope.   Power lines, on the other hand, would be on topic.  We've had quite a few questions about interfacing with and designing high-power systems, but no one employed by a utility has asked a question yet.  But, speaking of topicality, we're getting off topic for this comment thread, aren't we?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It requires a developer. The only text ♦ mods can change that normal users can't is the first section of the FAQ, "What kind of questions can I ask here?". If adding an element counts, mods can also create a system message that's displayed at the top of the screen, if there's something important that everyone needs to know about. Other than that they can't change any of the standard copy that appears on all Stack Exchange sites